# Unable to get data of a line chart and bar chart in a Cognos report using Cognos Mash-up service?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

Trying to get data of a report **employee satisfaction** in the sample cognos reports folder using

http://lxxxxx:9300/bi/v1/disp/rds/reportData/report/iED4FABBAF84C47EBA65B8A44FDCEF444?fmt=DataSetJSON

attached image of the output of the restcall, I am not getting data for Survey topic scores which is line chart and also EMPLOYEE RANKING which is bar chart.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpiyv.png)

why am i not able to get line chart and bar chart data? How to achieve this?

Comment: Your post is confusing.  Are you saying you are not getting the chart?  Or are you saying you are not getting the query output that feeds the chart?  I think CMS will only get you things that actually appear on the report page.  If you want the data, you'll need to add a list or crosstab to the page.

Comment: @dougp , I need to get data behind the report, As said i am able to get data for the Combination chart,list and cross tab but not for line chart or bar chart, How to get data behind line chart or bar chart using mash up service?